# Mongodb Sleepy Mongoose http interface regex not working

Tags: mongodb, http, database, nosql

I am using a sleepy mongoose http interface to search through a collection in mongodb that is running on a remote server.
I am having an issue with the regex inside the http url that I use to search for a pattern in one of the json documents in mongodb.

If I use

```
...?criteria={"type":"book"}
```

it returns me all json objects that have type parameter matching "book" as a complete string.

However, if I use

```
...?criteria={"type":{"$regex":"book", "$options":"i"}}
```

it returns me all json objects that have type parameter matching "book" as a substring but fails to match types that have a complete substring as "book". So I lose out on complete match.

In order to get both, should I call both the above queries twice?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Mongoose. The second regex works fine in the MongoDB Shell.

Comment: Could you recommend another http interface to do a regex search properly?

Comment: See the [HTTP Interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces) section in the MongoDB documentation or try [MongoLab's](https://mongolab.com/home) [REST API](https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-REST-API-for-MongoDB)